# What is a "contingent argument" (outside of law or theology)?

Tags: logic

I heard John McWhorter use this term and as best I could tell he was referring to an argument based on a something existing in the world rather than on logic.  E.g., I feel offended, so therefore what you said is offensive.
Would appreciate any refinement or corrections if this is totally off...

Answer (score 1):

The truth of a proposition may depend on a second proposition. The first is contingent on the second.

“All men are equal, if men is understood to be men and women”. “All men are equal” is then contingent on the second argument.